# Can I connect RFID tag to a microprocessor?

Tags: rfid, passive-components

Is it possible to connect a passive RFID tag to a microprocessor and functions as a receiver? I am new in this, so I need a bit of advice on how to do it. I've heard that it is possible but I know no methods how.

I want the tag to function as a receiver and receive data given from devices like NFC-enabled smartphones, transmit the data to the microprocessor (I'm using Attiny45), and activate a certain circuit. I'm using passive RFID, that is the same used inside passive RFID cards (due to its frequency, 947 MHz).

Comment: AFAIK RFID tags are intended to transmit data not receive.

Comment: @nidhun only the tags that are meant to be read only. Smarter tags can be written. Like nfc tags.

Comment: Are you trying to use any rfid tag or that specific tag? Because you can make your own tag with a coil or inductor http://hackaday.com/2011/05/20/using-an-avr-as-an-rfid-tag/

Answer (score 2):

There are few RFID chips with I2C capability. Murata Magicstrap is one such device. As for a general purpose receiver, it is not very useful. There are MCUs with NFC interface, from the usual suspects (TI, NXP).

Comment: Is the Magicstrap connectable to the Attiny45 in a circuitboard to transport data?

Answer (score 0):

NXP and TI ( even perhaps ST Microelectronics) have NFC/HF RFID SoC chips available that could do the job.

NXP's RC522 is the most common with widespread support for integration and lots of documentation to help you.